Space of complex $2 \times 2 \times 2$ tensors whose subtensors are pairwise orthogonal
I want to describe the space of all complex $2 \times 2 \times 2$ tensors whose subtensors are pairwise orthogonal. This means that if the tensor $T$ is denoted by $a_{i,j,k}$, then the following three equations must hold:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^2 \sum_{j=1}^2 a_{i,j,1} \overline{a_{i,j,2}} = 0
$$
$$
\sum_{i=1}^2 \sum_{k=1}^2 a_{i,1,k} \overline{a_{i,2,k}} = 0
$$
$$
\sum_{j=1}^2 \sum_{k=1}^2 a_{1,j,k} \overline{a_{2,j,k}} = 0
$$
Also how would this be generalize to higher dimension tensors and tensors that have larger size?
